# unwanted partitions

Tags: gparted, partitioning

I was recently exploring my drive partitions through Gparted in Ubuntu, when I saw this:

[image: My Disk Partition in gparted]

Why do I have so many partitions? I originally had only 5 (`C:/`, `Recovery`, and 3 others; I dual boot with Windows 10) then I installed Ubuntu and I should have 2 more, one `ext4` type and the other is the Linux `swap`.

Where did the `sda1`, `sda2`, `sda4`, `sda8` and unallocated partitions come from? 
Can I get rid of them? Should I?

Answer (score 2):

> Where did the sda1,

That is your boot partition (EFI files are stored here)

> sda2, sda4, sda8

Off topic. Those are microsoft partitions so we are not going to be able to answer that here. Want a guess? Recovery partitions. (windows RE tools: RE is for recovery).

> unallocated partitions come from?

Those are dividers. With EFI partitions there was also a divider of 1 Mb between different filesystems introduced. Some partition tools hide these from you. GParted does not.

> Can I get rid of them? Should I?

- Unallocated partitions. No and no.
- If you want you can delete any recovery partition. Unless you ever want to recover your system to the way it was when bought. Make sure you save any mandatory license key you may need before deleting recovery partitions.

---

sda1, sda10, sda11 are directly related to Linux. sda1 and all others are directly related to Windows.